# How to stream (RTMP) video from iOS Device (not from its own camera)

Tags: ios, streaming, rtmp, videocore

I want to send a external video from my iOS device.
This video is being received from a live streaming: **RTSP server** or **HLS url** (not from iPhone camera).

Currently I can stream my camera video from **iPhone** using `VideoCore` (internally using `CameraSource` and `MicSource`) but now, the video I want to stream comes from an URL. Similar to [Periscope streaming video from GoPro Cam](https://gopro.com/help/articles/Block/Periscope-Live-Streaming-with-your-GoPro).

**Problem 1:**  I don't know how to extract from a RTSP URL audio and video

**Problem 2:** I don't know how to create a `CameraSource` o `MicSource` from this extracted video and audio.

Do you know where to find an example or could you help me with this technical challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a first approach for the first problem:

```
  AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:URL];
    AVAsset *asset = [item asset];

    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{
        if ([asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:nil] == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded) {
            NSArray *videoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

            //VIDEO
            //videoOutput is a AVPlayerItemVideoOutput * property
            [item addOutput:self.videoOutput];

            //AUDIO
            AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *inputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:[audioTracks objectAtIndex:0]];
            MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks callbacks;            
            callbacks.version = kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0;
            callbacks.clientInfo = (__bridge void *)self,
            callbacks.init = tap_InitCallback;
            callbacks.finalize = tap_FinalizeCallback;
            callbacks.prepare = tap_PrepareCallback;
            callbacks.unprepare = tap_UnprepareCallback;
            callbacks.process = tap_ProcessCallback;            
            MTAudioProcessingTapRef tap;
            OSStatus err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks,
                                                      kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap);           
            inputParams.audioTapProcessor = tap;
            AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
            audioMix.inputParameters = @[inputParams];
            item.audioMix = audioMix;    
    }];
```

Then create a callback with `CADisplayLink` which will callback `displayPixelBuffer`: at every vsync.

```
 self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkCallback:)];
    [[self displayLink] addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[self displayLink] setPaused:YES];
```

and in this method get pixelBuffer and send to output
For Audio, do similar tasks in prepare callback using `AURenderCallbackStruct`.

Comment: Hey @Bisca, Do you have detail code how to make RTMP connection too? I am trying to live on Facebook from Assets video.

Comment: @AJit I don't have an example... You can try using VideoCore (https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore-Inactive) or lf (https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift) or another implementation to do this and use as source this pixelBuffer

Comment: Thanks @Bisca for quick replay, I have already implemented VideoCore but it support with CameraSource only atm, I am not that good with C++ programming to tweak the source, so if you could help here somehow?
This is reference i have taken : https://github.com/kciter/FBLiveAPISample-iOS